# How to duplicate specific rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I need to create a copy of certain rows. I don't want to change the table.

So I need a query that creates the copies on the fly.

Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE [Test](
[id1] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[id2] [int] NOT NULL,
[chk] [int] NOT NULL,
[ref] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

```
INSERT INTO [Test]
VALUES
(4,1,1,'ab'),
(4,2,0,'cd'),
(5,2,0,'ef'),
(6,1,0,'gh'),
(6,2,1,'ij'),
(7,1,0,'kl'),
(7,2,0,'mn'),
(8,1,1,'op'),
(8,2,1,'qr'),
(8,3,1,'st'),
(9,1,1,'uv'),
(9,2,1,'wx'),
(10,1,1,'yz'),
(10,2,1,'?!')
```

I need the first row of every id1 as a copy.
corresponding id2 will be given the value 0

I came up with this query

```
Select * from Test 
Where chk = 1
Union All
Select a.id1, 0, 0, a.ref From Test a
Inner Join (Select id1, Min(id2) as matchid From Test
            Group By id1) b On a.id1 = b.id1 ANd a.id2 = b.matchid
Order By id1, id2
```

It works, but maybe you know a more specific way to do this.

Comment: `JOIN` the `VALUES` table construct containing the values `0` and `1` when the value of `id2` is `1`?

Comment: there is no guarantee that for any id1 an id2 = 1 exists.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't demonstrate that; they *all* have a `id2` of `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a sequential integer to each row within a partition

```
SELECT * 
FROM Test 
WHERE chk = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id1, 0, 0, a.ref 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY id2) AS rn
  FROM Test
) as a
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id1, id2
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1 ORDER BY id2) AS row_num
```

to assign a row number to each row within each id1 group, ordered by id2.

You can also use SELECT ...... AS subquery AS row_num expression to assign a row number to each row within each id1 group, ordered by id2.